# Android SQLite to My MySQL Web Server?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have been learning SQLite on Android and have done some tutorials on how to use it.
There is a question that I want to ask. 
Is there a way to make my app connect to my MySQL database in a remote web server of mine so that it can read data and also write data to the database?

From what I've researched, SQLite cannot be used remotely and I would need some kind of Web service in between?

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to create a connection to MySQL from Android, if it's not impossible. With that, it's also not safe if for example someone decompiles your app they have access to your whole MySQL database if you don't limit it enough.

For those reasons, you can better use a (for example) PHP webservice to which the Android application sends all their requests. An example is available at http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database.

I also suggest you use [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) so you don't have to deal with connectivity issues and AsyncTasks yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) but you do need a web-server for it.

Request mechanism
Android App ----> webserver  ------> database (mysql)

Respond mechanism
Android App <---- webserver  <------ database (mysql)

Android App will use [JSON](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) or [other](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) to get the data and display it

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Sqlite database and web Services both. First you have to save the data in local database i.e. SQLite database and then send this data to your server using web services and vice versa.

[this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) for web services

and [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) for SQlite will help you understand.

Thanks.

Comment: I wish this answer was a little more elaborate. You save the data on the android memory using SQLite, and then have a hook to send send it to web service. That is two steps. Why not just send to remote server sometimes, and use SQLite other times. But what if you have an app that has both a web service and mobile, you want databases to be in sync. How you sync databases?